# Print a specific column from a tab-delimited file in python

Tags: python, split, csv

I am a beginner with python. I have a  tab-delimited file and I want to print only the 37th column which is the last column. But when I run this code the whole data is printed. my code goes as follows:

```py
dicts = {}
for i in open('Book2.txt'):
    split_i = i.split('\t')
    dicts[split_i[37]] = i.rstrip()
    print(i.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 4, rstrip() is a string function to remove trailing whitespace, not to grab the last word. Since split() created a list from the string in the previous line, you can use list indexing, like split_i[-1] to index the rightmost item of the list, or split_i[36] to get the 37th from the left.
Additionally, this may not be the right use of a dict. Try creating a list instead, such as:

```
col_37 = []                        # Empty list instead of a dict
for line in open('Book2.txt'):     # Variable 'i' named more intuitively
    split_line = line.split('\t')  # Separate the string by tabs
    col_37.append(split_line[36])  # Add the item you want to your list
print(col_37)                      # Show the data you just got
```

Comment: `split_i[37]` is not the 37th from the left.

Answer (score 0):

Lists in python are [zero indexed](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists). which means the first element has an index of 0. So for the 37th column it would be `mylist[36]`. Since you want the last column there is a shortcut `mylist[-1]` which always returns the last element of the list.

```
for line in open('Book2.txt'):
    print(line.split('\t')[-1])
```

[List comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#using-list-comprehensions) is a much cleaner and more pythonic approach to handle a simple `for loop`:

```
lines = open('Boot2.txt')
col = [line.split('\t')[-1].rstrip() for line in lines]
print("\n".join(col))
```